# navigator.serviceWorker for development environment

Tags: javascript, web-push

`serviceWorker` in `navigator` available only if web page is loaded via https.
Is there any way to make it working on development environment using usual http?

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    console.log('serviceWorker');
}
```

It does not wok on my development environment.

I'm using firefox/chrome as a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MDN: Service workers are restricted to running across HTTPS for security reasons. GitHub is therefore a good place to host experiments, as it supports HTTPS. In order to facilitate local development, localhost is considered a secure origin by browsers as well.

So I would run your dev environment on a localhost port and it should work